# Using -d to check if dir exists fails sometimes

Tags: perl

```
-d $Dir or make_path( $Dir) or die "Can't mkdir $Dir: $!";
```

I have this line of code, but less than 1% of the time the script fails saying:

```
mkdir <$Dir path>: File exists at script.pl line 234
```

anything wrong with the way I used "-d" and "or" ?

Comment: Does it ever fail, then work, on the same directory string? If not, can you provide an example of a directory string which fails, and let us know what platform you are running on?

Comment: @toolic, the point of `-d` is to avoid the `die` if the directory exists. That said, the `die` is totally useless since `make_path` already dies on error. As such, the code can be reduced to just `make_path($Dir);`.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are trying to create a directory with the same name as an existing (plain) file. `-d` returns false since the target is not a directory. Then `make_path` dies since it can't create the requested directory.